# Java JDBC select records

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm working on a little project and right now I have a problem. I need to search in my database all movies which have same genre. I wrote this function for this thing, but doesn't work so well. In principle I want for each result found to create a new object named Movie and to return him. I tested my function but I have two movies with same gerne and he return me only one object. And my question is why doesn't return me all objects? He should to return all my objects.

```
public Movie extraction(String Genre)throws SQLException{
    Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from movies where genre='"+Genre+"'");
    while(rs.next()){
        String name=rs.getString("name");
        String genre=rs.getString("genre");
        int year=rs.getInt("year");
        int metascore=rs.getInt("metascore");
        System.out.println(name);
        return new Movie(name,genre,year,metascore);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You are using `return` inside your loop, so it exits at the first iteration.Add your objects to a list instead, and return the list after the loop .

Comment: Do yourself a favor and learn about PreparedStatement.  You should not SELECT *; spell out the columns you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you `return` within the loop instead of adding the results to a `List` and returning that list when the loop completes.

There are several other issues with the code which are not related to your problem but may create problems in the future:

1. You create a statement and a resultset and never close them.
2. You are using string concatenation to generate the query instead of a `PreparedStatement`. If the string `Genere` is received from some untrusted user (for example in a web application) that user may use SQL injection to transform the query into whatever he wants.

A better solution (warning: untested) is something like the following:

```
List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();

try(PreparedStatement stmt= con.prepareStament("select * from movies where genre=?")) {
  stmt.setString(1, Genere);
  try(ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
    while(rs.next()){
      String name=rs.getString("name");
      String genre=rs.getString("genre");
      int year=rs.getInt("year");
      int metascore=rs.getInt("metascore");
      movies.add(new Movie(name,genre,year,metascore));
    }
  }
}
return movies;
```

the `try` statement (called "try with resources") ensures that the statement and the resultset `.close` methods are called when the block ends.

Comment: But I don't want to add in my list inside on my function, I want only to return all the objects. Because the first time I did as you said. And right now I want another approach.

Comment: The only way to return all objects is to place them in some container (a collections class -- a list, a set or similar)

Comment: I thought there were more possibilities.